# How to refactor long union type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapped-types

I want to create a React functional component which takes one of the predefined components as a prop and which logic depends on what component was passed in.

So these are the possible names:

```js
enum ComponentName {
  ComponentA: "component.a",
  ComponentB: "component.b",
  ComponentC: "component.c",
  // etc
}
```

Now the hard part, I have a bunch of Component types, which names are all in the enum, like:

```js
type ComponentA = {
  attributes: {
    // ...
  }
}

type ComponentB = {
  attributes: {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now what I want to do is somehow to define type Component, so that:

```js
type Component = 
| {
    id: string;
    name: ComponentName.ComponentA;
    component: ComponentA;
  }
| {
    id: string;
    name: ComponentName.ComponentB;
    component: ComponentB;
  }
| // ...
```

Is there a way to simplify this union type by mapping over `ComponentName` enum and matching enum prop to Component type name?

Comment: Type *names* aren’t accessible as strings.  You’ll need to maintain such a mapping yourself. Given that mapping you could compute `Component` from it, though. I’ll show how when I get to a real computer, and see if that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have some sort of mappings between component names and their attributes `ComponentMappings`, then you can create a union from that mapping using a helper function like

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
```

`Values` generates a union type from the values of a mapped type or object.

```
enum ComponentName {
  ComponentA = "component.a",
  ComponentB = "component.b",
  ComponentC = "component.c",
}

type ComponentMappings = {
  [ComponentName.ComponentA]: {
    attributes: {
      className: string;
    };
  };
  [ComponentName.ComponentB]: {
    attributes: {
      className: string;
      foo: number;
    };
  };
  [ComponentName.ComponentC]: {
    attributes: {
      className: string;
    };
  };
};

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type Component = Values<{
  [K in ComponentName]: {
    id: string;
    name: K;
    component: ComponentMappings[K];
  };
}>;

const comopnentA: Component = {
  name: ComponentName.ComponentA,
  id: "component-a",
  component: {
    attributes: {
      className: "flex",
    },
  },
};

const componentB: Component = {
  name: ComponentName.ComponentB,
  id: "component-B",
  component: {
    attributes: {
      className: "flex",
      foo: 3,
    },
  },
};
```

[TypesSript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThYwCWAzEAeAKgPigXigG8BYAKCigG0BpKZAOygGsIQB7VKLAXQC5utHgG5yAXygAyYmNFlyEBgFcAtlADC7FWHYNFwAHIBDFdFIUNWnXobAAggSgAiAMZXd%20gHRGnAGnKUmtoetgBCjq7uNsCeAEZ%20AZbB0eoRbsleLglkYuTkoJBJ1voAskZgYIwA5gDOjuaUVEHFtsamns0h9vzEiZRGSHDIsUrAEDUCDZTTLgA2RjU1bRACNcBDDFVy01CyiXsWTVH6yx3HYT1T-YPDo%20OTfTPzi8ur69XbO1Co7OwCyipYhA4J9KAcwZ8jhlWiYIGdocB1JdHgN3iMxhNehYdnMFktYW8NltHuDdnIDvlwNAAGpGWZKcbYPCELBUVgcLi8OSUwqdaIEeCIFDoDC0%20mMqa0ehMPknWHI7H0AAmhI%20jwYBKgNFBUHSLWAAlltjKFWqNSEnwOYhwODyZDcDDWuq07DA0TshvOwHqiQ1pk9CNORvs-gsyBVzj1XQAtD5Q5Qo9EHorUUN0fcsV9dc98f7nKhZhAAB7ZHZieO7UMU%2026J2J-ShAP6n0WP0rIpdINe0IV8MCSII6OhUvOhHJnap24Y8dfXEvTVOAvFkc7H5-KAAZhJFfL4m5ZCAA)

Note that `Prettify` type in the playground does nothing and just makes it more readable when you hover on the type.